# Equality of norms for two functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space over $\mathbb{C}$ with finite amount of dimensions, especially let's assume that $ix, x \in X$ is well defined. Moreover let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous $
\mathbb{R}$-linear (i.e. is linear only with respect to constants from $\mathbb{R}$) functional. Now, let's define another functional $g: X \to \mathbb{C}$
$$g(u) = f(u) - if(iu), \qquad u \in X.$$
I would like to show that $\lvert \lvert g\rvert \rvert = \lvert \lvert f\rvert \rvert$.

I tried to show it as simple as possible, i.e. using two inequalities $\lvert \lvert g\rvert \rvert \ge \lvert \lvert f\rvert \rvert$ and $\lvert \lvert g\rvert \rvert \le \lvert \lvert f\rvert \rvert$. Since $f$ it's continuous then it's also bounded thus
$$\lvert g \rvert = \lvert f(u) - if(iu) \rvert \le \lvert f \rvert + \lvert f \rvert.$$

Unfortunately taking the $\sup$ on both sides does not give us the expected result. I suppose I should use another approach.

**Edit**

Thanks to the tip provided by Guillermo I managed to show that $ ||g||\leq ||f||$. According to that tip there exist $r \ge 0$ and $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(u) = re^{i\theta}$. After a few calculations we conclude that
$$|g(u)| = r = g(u)e^{-i\theta} = g(e^{-i\theta} u),$$
because $g$ is linear.

Now, due to the fact then $g(e^{-i\theta} u) \in \mathbb{R}$ we get the following equality $g(e^{-i\theta} u) = f(e^{-i\theta} u)$. On the other hand $|g(u)| = f(e^{-i\theta}u)$.

If $||u|| = 1$ then, obviously $|g(u)| \le \sup_{||u|| = 1} |f(u)|$. Taking, once again, supremum on both sides we conclude that $||g|| \le ||f||$.

Nów I would like to show the other part of, i.e. $||g|| \ge ||f||$. I thing I might show it this way. Let $u$ be fixed and $||u|| = 1$. We have
$$||g|| \ge |g(u)| = |f(u) - if(iu)|.$$
For a fixed $u$ the RHS is just a complex number, thus
$$|f(u) - if(iu)| = \sqrt{|f(u)|^2 + |f(iu)|^2} \ge |f(u)|.$$

We have $||g|| \ge |f(u)|$ for some fixed $u \in X$. Now we can take the supremum on both sides. We get $||g|| \ge ||f||$ which ends the proof.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: How are you defining $iu$ if $X$ is an arbitrary space?

Comment: @wflewis You're right. Let $X$ not be totally arbitrary. I edited my question.

Comment: When you say "$ix$ is well defined", what exactly do you mean?  That $X$ can be considered as a vector space over $\mathbb C$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$g(u)=f(u)-if(iu)=f(u)-i^2f(u)=f(u)+f(u)=2f(u),$$ so $$||g||=2||f||,$$ so your result is false. After the edit, since $g(u)\in\mathbb{C}$, there exist some $r\geq 0$ and $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ such as $g(u)=re^{i\theta}.$ Then we have that $$|g(u)|=r=e^{-i\theta}g(u)=g(e^{-i\theta}u).$$ So $$g(e^{-i\theta}u)=f(e^{-i\theta}u)\implies||g||\leq ||f||.$$ Can you conclude from here?

Comment: You're right. That's because of my wrong definition of $f$. I need a function $f$ which is linear only with respect to $\mathbb{R}$. I will edit my question.

Comment: Thank you! The implication is pretty straight forward but I can't see why $g(e^{-i\theta}u)=f(e^{-i\theta}u)$?

Comment: Because $g$ evaluated in that point is equal yo its norm, so its a real number and It implies that is equal to the real part

Comment: Oh, now I see. We use the fact that $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$. Obviously we have $e^{-i\theta}u = v \in X$, because $e^{-i\theta}$ just rotates the vector. What about the other inequality? I think that the simple triangle inequality is not enough. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

It's not true in general.  Consider $X = \mathbb R^2$ with the sup norm $\|x\| = \max(|x_1|, |x_2|)$, and $i (x_1, x_2) = (-x_2, x_1)$.  Take $f(x) = x_1$, which has $\|f\| = 1$,
i.e. $|f(x)| = |x_1| \le \|x\|$, with equality whenever $|x_2| \le |x_1|$.  Now $g(x) = f(x) - i f(ix) = x_1 + i x_2$, so $|g(x)| = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2} > \|x\|$ whenever $x_1$ and $x_2$ are both nonzero.

Comment: Indeed, $X$ has to be over $\mathbb{C}$. Thanks for that example!